# Can not using Bloodhound in website (Error: Bloodhound is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typehead

I want to use Typehead for input field but it appeared following error

> Bloodhound is not defined

I already implement some library

```
<script src="jquery/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var courses = ['PRN292', 'SWT201', 'PRO201', 'JPD201'];
        var courses = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: courses
        });

        $('.typehead').typehead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
            },
            {
            name: 'courses',
            source: courses
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h2>Course code</h2>
    <input type="search" class="typehead" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

Comment: Try putting the script tag for jquery before typeahead. Also it is odd that you are loading both normal and minified version of the typeahead.bundle.js.

Comment: I tried your recommend and now it appear following error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typehead is not a function`.

Comment: Check your spelling. It should be "typeahead".

Comment: oh my god, my mistake! Thank you for your concern.